# Python media error serving RSS feed

Tags: python, xml, apache, rss

Centos 6, Python 3.4 and serving with Bottle.

The feed validates BUT "Feeds should not be served with the "text/html" media type".

Wouldn't .xml file type automatically and application/rss+xml ?

Feed at http://pythom.com/api/rss.xml

Tnx
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Need to add header info in the def.

bottle.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/rss+xml'

Now validating.